# Slopes and Tangents Calculus

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

a) **Normal to a curve** Find an equation for the line perpendicular to the tangent to the curve $y = x^3 - 4x + 1$ at the point $(2,1)$.

b)**Smallest Slope** What is the smallest slope on the curve?At what point on the curve does the curve have this slope?

c)**Tangents having specified slope** Find equations for the tangents to the curve at the points where the slope of the curve is $8$.

The first question is fairly obvious as differentiating the curve gives you the slope at the given point and then finding the equation of a line perpendicular to that tangent is fairly easy, I'm stuck with the next question  where I'm asked to find the smallest slope on the curve.

Is there a property or any particular arithmetical way to determine the same?

Comment: My question is how to determine the smallest slope on the curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (b): The slope at a point on the graph of the given equation is given by $y'=3x^2-4$ i.e. by $f(x)=3x^2-4$. The smallest slope is given by the minimum value of $f$. It's not difficult to see that $f(x)$ is a parabola so the minimum value is attained at the local minimum which occurs at $x=0$, namely at point $(0,1)$ on the curve you have. Then $$\min{f}=f(0)=-4.$$

**EDIT:** After you differentiate and find the function whose value is the slope e.g. $f(x)=3x^2-4$ you then need to find the minimum. Finding local minimum: $f'(x)=6x$, set this equal to $0$: $f'(x)=0$ when $x=0$. Then $f''(x)=6>0$ so the critical point $x=0$ of $f$ is a local minimum. Since
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)= +\infty \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=+\infty
$$
we deduce that the global minimum of $f(x)$ is the local minimum value which is $f(x)|_{x=0}=f(0)=-4$.

Comment: Hi Thanks! Is there any other method to determine the smallest slope apart from the concluding the fact that the given function is a parabola as in if the function were to be y= x^3 -3x - 2, how would you determine the smallest slope?

Comment: I edited my answer.